# Void pointers and dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm trying to make a word counter program that takes a sentence and counts the number of words. I would like to use dynamic memory allocation because it has many advantages such as not having to worry about not enough space or too much empty space. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *strmalloc(const char *string);
char *user_input = NULL;

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter a sentence to find out the number of words: ");
    strmalloc(user_input);
    return 0;
}

const char *strmalloc(const char *string) {
    char *tmp = NULL;
    size_t size = 0, index = 0;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        if (size <= index) {
            size += 1;
            tmp = realloc((char*)string, size);
        }
    }
}
```

As you might know, the prototype for the realloc function goes like this:

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
```

When I use the realloc function in the while loop in the `strmalloc()` function, I get a warning saying:

```
Passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers
```

I have no idea what this means but I know that I can get rid of it with a typecast to `char*`

However, I've learned that I shouldn't use a typecast just to prevent a warning. I should learn what the warning is warning me about and decide whether a typecast is the right thing. But then again, I know that a pointer to void accepts any data type, and to specify one, a typecast is required. So my question is, should I keep the typecast in the `realloc()` function or get rid of it and do something else.

Comment: A [qualifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_qualifier) is a keyword such as `volatile` or `const` that modifies a type. Does that help?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks for answering that part of the question but I still have the main question unanswered. If you do know the answer please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: It'll lead you to the right answer. You are correct to want to avoid casting away the warning. There's a better solution than casting away `const`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, Sorry I don't think I understand. Can you please tell me what you're getting at?

Comment: [Do not cast away a const qualification.](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP05-C.+Do+not+cast+away+a+const+qualification) The `remove_spaces` example is very similar to your code.

Comment: (Sorry that I'm being oblique. I thought you might like to figure out the answer yourself since your question shows good curiosity about doing things right.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` is a type qualifier. In the `C` and maybe in many other programming languages, `const` applied to a data type  indicates that the data is read only.

> Passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers

The above error you are getting because you are passing `const` object to a parameter that is not `const` ( `(void *)` in `realloc`), and warning you about there is a possibility of changing (discards) the values pointed by `const char* string` by using `void* ptr`, that defeats the whole purpose of declaring the data as `const`.

But looking at the example, you are trying to allocate a memory for `char* string`, and after allocation, you would want to write something into that memory, if you make it `const`, how do expect it to write.

So you don't need your `char* string` to be `const` and hence , there is no need of cast to `char*` in `realloc`.

Comment: Thanks @IrAM, You're right about not being able to change the `const char *string` value. I didn't know what I was thinking. But thanks!